# How to merge two files with a common key in awk?

Tags: awk

I have two files k1 and k2 and I am trying to merge both files based on the common key 'Name of Book'.

k1

```
John | Dreaming of Day | IEEEJournal
Akon | Dreaming of Night | ACMJournal
```

k2

```
Dreaming of Day | Fiction
Dreaming of Night | Non-Fiction
```

kout: Should merge based on Name of Book ie `Dreaming of Day` and `Dreaming of Night`

```
John | Fiction | IEEEJournal
Akon | Non-Fiction | ACMJournal
```

I have written below awk script:

```
 awk -F"|" 'BEGIN{OFS="|"}FNR==NR{a[$1$2]=$3;next}($1$2 in a && $3=$3"|"a[$1$2])' k1 k2
```

But it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: please do not cross-post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40811963/how-to-merge-two-files-with-a-common-key-in-awk ... see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu

Comment: @Sundeep: Sure, I wasnt aware about this. I will delete the question from here. I was in need of urgent help. So asked at both places. Do you want me to delete the post from here?

Answer (score 3):

This seems to work in both `gawk` and `mawk`:

```
awk -F' *[|] *' -vOFS=' | ' '
  NR==FNR {a[$1]=$2;next} $2 in a {print $1, a[$2], $3}
' k2 k1
John | Fiction | IEEEJournal
Akon | Non-Fiction | ACMJournal
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the reason that it is not working is that field 2 of file 1 is not equal to field 1 of file2.
Using '|' as delimiter , field 1 of file 2 is "Dreaming of Day", while field 2 on file 1 is " Dreaming of Day". There is an extra space before word Dreaming.

I tried to do your example with join command, and it didn't worked due to this extra space. If you remove the extra space of field 2 - file 1 (or add an extra space in field1-file2), it should work.

PS1: By the way with join (and by removing the extra space) you can go pretty close in your desired result without the need of a "script" :

```
join --nocheck-order -t"|" -1 2 a.txt b.txt
```

Output (after removing all extra spacee in front of all | ):

```
Dreaming of Day |John |IEEEJournal|Fiction
Dreaming of Night |Akon |ACMJournal|Non-Fiction
```

You can then cut -d'|' the required fields

PS2: There is always the "classic way" that works with your data (no need to remove extra space)

```
while IFS="|" read -r line title1 rest; do
title2=$(echo $title1)
genre=$(grep -e "$title2" b.txt |cut -f2 -d"|")
echo $line "|" $genre "|" $rest    
done <a.txt
```

Output:

```
John | Fiction | IEEEJournal
Akon | Non-Fiction | ACMJournal
```